# Авторизация через oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth2

Как сделать так чтобы можно быстро авторизовываться через authentication server без секретного ключа?

Как я знаю в keycloak используется oauth2, но там можно сделать так, чтобы при авторизации через определенный client_id не нужно было передавать секретный ключ, но перерыв интернет я не нашел как это сделать это на чтобы spring boot через username и password с использованием spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 и spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server.